# ¿Cómo crear 'n' cantidad de vectores en C?

Tags: c, array, dev-c++, programación-funcional

**Hola , que tal!**

Necesito pedirle al usuario cuántos vectores quiere crear, y luego preguntarle el tamaño de cada vector.

Ejemplo:

Si el quiere crear 3 vectores, se crea vector [a], vector [b] y [c].
y luego el usuario quiere que el vector[a] tenga 5 elementos y el [b] 3 elementos y asì sucesivamente para luego llenarlos con caracteres.

Todo esto en Lenguaje C (Uso Dev-C++)
¿Se podrá?

Comment: Sí. Puedes tener un array de punteros. La primera respuesta del usuario (3) te sirve para dar un tamaño a ese array (guardará tres punteros). Después cada uno de los punteros se inicializará apuntando a otro array de elementos, cada uno del tamaño adecuado. Para todas estas reservas de memoria debes usar `malloc()` (y cuando ya no necesites los vectores, liberarla con `free()`, primero la de cada vector y luego la del array de punteros). Eso sí, los vectores no se llamarán `a`, `b` y `c`, sino por ejemplo `array[0]`, `array[1]`, etc... Los elementos de uno de ellos serían p.ej: `array[0][i]`

Comment: @abulafia Gracias! Basandome en eso, me ha surgido otra duda:  estoy utilizando una sola variable para leer la cantidad de elementos de cada array, por ejemplo si el usuario quiere que el array tenga 3 elementos lo leo con la variable *a*, pido que llene el vector y luego continuo con el siguiente,el array [1] y lo leo nuevamente con la variable *a*. Al presentar el array [0] en pantalla, ya no tengo el valor de los elementos que leì con la variable *a*, ya que esta fue sobreescrita por el array[1]. ¿Cómo puedo guardar la cantidad de elementos de cada array, de la mejor manera?

Comment: La respuesta a esta última cuestión necesita un poco de espacio... Te lo pondré en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres en el fondo es un array en el que cada uno de los elementos sea un vector (de diferentes longitudes, además).

La forma de lograrlo es tener un array de punteros, de modo que cada uno de estos punteros apunte a otro vector. Supongamos que cada uno de los vectores es de enteros. Una primera aproximación sería por tanto:

```
int *array[];
```

Supongamos que queremos 3 arrays, de longitudes 10, 20 y 30. Entonces inicializaríamos este array así:

```
array = malloc(3*sizeof(int*));
array[0] = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
array[1] = malloc(20*sizeof(int));
array[2] = malloc(30*sizeof(int));
```

Ahora bien, los arrays dinámicos en C (los que se crean con `malloc()` como los que acabamos de ver) tienen un importante problema. Si bien mediante un puntero podemos acceder a la dirección en la que comienzan, no hay forma de saber la dirección en la que terminan porque *su tamaño no queda almacenado en ningún lugar*.

Esto nos lleva a la duda que has planteado en un comentario a la pregunta, y que reproduzco a continuación:

> estoy utilizando una sola variable para leer la cantidad de elementos de cada array, por ejemplo si el usuario quiere que el array tenga 3 elementos lo leo con la variable a, pido que llene el vector y luego continuo con el siguiente,el array [1] y lo leo nuevamente con la variable a. Al presentar el array [0] en pantalla, ya no tengo el valor de los elementos que leì con la variable a, ya que esta fue sobreescrita por el array[1]. ¿Cómo puedo guardar la cantidad de elementos de cada array, de la mejor manera?

Ya que C no te da forma alguna de saber cuántos elementos tiene el array una vez creado, tendrás que guardar esa información tú mismo en algún lugar.

Una solución podría ser tener otro vector de enteros, en el cual cada elemento representa el número de elementos del otro vector. En ese caso el código sería así:

```
int *array[];
int longitudes[];
int a;
int i;

printf("Cuántos vectores quieres crear? ");
scanf("%d", &a);
array = malloc(a*sizeof(int*));
longitudes = malloc(a*sizeof(int));
for (i=0; i<a; i++) {
   printf("Cuántos elementos quieres para el vector %d: ", i);
   scanf("%d", &a);
   longitudes[i] = a;
   array[i] = malloc(a * sizeof(int));
}
```

Otra posible opción es que los vectores, en lugar de ser un mero puntero, sean una estructura con dos campos. Uno de los campos guardaría el tamaño del vector, y el otro el puntero a dónde comienza. En este caso quedaría así (se complica un poco porque hay un nivel más de indirección):

```
struct vector {
  int n_elem;
  int *v;
};
typedef struct vector vector;

vector *array[];
vector *aux;
int a;
int i;

printf("Cuántos vectores quieres crear? ");
scanf("%d", &a);
array = malloc(a*sizeof(vector*));
for (i=0; i<a; i++) {
   aux = malloc(sizeof(vector));
   printf("Cuántos elementos quieres para el vector %d: ", i);
   scanf("%d", &a);
   aux->n_elem = a;
   aux->v = malloc(a * sizeof(int));
   array[i] = aux;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @abulafia , no pudo haber mejor explicación que ésta, te lo agradezco mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Ya que no puedo comentar puedes hacerlo utilizando la  expresion `sizeof`

Ademas puedes revisar este post.

> [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: Por desgracia `sizeof()` sólo te da el número de bytes que ocupa una variable. Si la variable es un array de tamaño fijo, a partir de ahí podrías sacar el número de elementos (que es lo que se explica en la cuestión que enlazas). Pero si lo que tienes es un puntero (como es el caso), `sizeof()` simplemente te da el tamaño del puntero, pero no el tamaño del lugar al que apunta, que no puede obtenerse de ningún modo.

Comment: @abulafia necesito tu ayuda nuevamente, no hace mucho hice otra publicacion al respecto :c